# Applovin Max SDK for Unity returns Error code -1004 when trying to ad load (Only iOS problem. Android works perfect)

Tags: unity-game-engine, sdk, max, ads, applovin

I'm intergrating Applovin Max SDK for Unity. But it has some problem.

Everything is perfect except iOS.
When i build and run on Android, it's perfect. But same same condifion of iOS phone, it can not load AD. The error code is -1004, but it's not defined in Max documents.
I think -1004 may not the Max's errorcode.
I guess It has possibility of NSURLErrorDomain error code.
But i'm not sure.

Anyway, is anybody have experienced this case?
Absolutely i asked Applovin via Q&A page, but they're not answer until  now. And i don't expect also they can solve this problem. Because they don't have technical Q&A page.(It's normal Q&A page)

Answer (score 0):

You're correct in that `-1004` maps to `NSURLErrorCannotConnectToHost`. I would advise emailing their support team at support@applovin.com and include the [SDK's verbose logs](https://monetization-support.applovin.com/hc/en-us/articles/236114328-How-do-I-enable-verbose-logging-in-AppLovin-s-SDK-) as well. They usually respond pretty quickly.